# On iPhone, how to open a book in format epub in the app Books?

Tags: iphone, books, epub

On my iPhone, in the app Files, I have a book in format epub. I want to open it in the app Books. This is simple. But I did not find any way.

When I click the book in the app Files, the iPhone goes in the app Books, but my book is not in it. I tried to open the book from the app Books. I found no way. I searched on the Web. I found no simple way.

How can I open the book in the app Books ?

[Added later :]

In the app Files, I long-click my book, I click *Share*, I choose *Open in Books*. Even this gives the app Books without book in it. Is this designed to work ?

Comment: I know this does not help, but what you describe is precisely how I have opened books many times. Is the file maybe corrupted?

Comment: @X_841 - Thank you, it does help ! So I deduce that what I do is designed to work. With Apple stuff, knowingly having a way which, in theory, works is already a good thing. Indeed, the file is maybe incorrect.

Comment: @X_841 - On 2 iPhones, clicking the file in Files brings the app Books and there is no book in it and there is no error message. On an iPhone, in the app Lisa, trying to import the file gives an error message. It would be good that the app Books from Apple on iPhone give an error message when trying to open an incorrect file. The file seems to be incorrect. I try to click another epub file in the app Files on an iPhone : this opens the book in the app Books !